# Thread problem executing async query inside ConnectableObservable

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, observable, rx-java

So I have a ConnectableObservable that receives Strings, for each of the Strings I need to do a Query (Async) and wait until the result comes back

At the moment I am using a latch to wait until the query comes back, but the observable its getting stuck or just finishing the first string and not continue with the others.

I have isolated the problem in this example

```
private Subscriber<? super String> stringStreamInput;

   ConnectableObservable<String> stringStream = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {
            stringStreamInput = subscriber;
        }
    })
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .map(new Func1<String, String>() {
                @Override
                public String call(String perro) {
                    return getPerroDetails(perro);
                }
            })
            .publish();
    stringStream.connect();
```

Method that calls the query simulation

```
  private String getPerroDetails(final String perro) {
        Log.d("Hey", "Perro " + perro);

        //Simulating the query to get Perro details
        String newPerro = executeQueryForPerro(perro);

        Log.d("Hey", "NewPerro  " + newPerro);
        return newPerro;
    }
```

Simulation of Query using CountDownLatch

```
private String executeQueryForPerro(final String perro) {
        final String[] newPerro = new String[1];
        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        //SIMULATION OF THE QUERY
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                newPerro[0] = perro + " reloaded ";
            latch.countdown();
            }
        }, 1000);

        try {
            latch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return newPerro[0];
    }
```

Test

```
 String[] perros = new String[]{"Beagle", "Alaska", "Chihuahua", "PitBull", "RedBull"};
    for (String perro : perros) {
        stringStreamInput.onNext(perro);
    }
```

What other approaches can I take to make sure the Query is executed properly and wait until the result comes back to go to the next step?

Is there any magic Rx solution for this?

Many Thanks

Comment: What does your logcat show? any errors propagating that are swallowed on the background thread?

Comment: No Errors that I can see, Iit just prints "D/Hey: Perro Beagle", I have tried creating a new Thread, instead of the handler postDelayed, and also using Loopers but the most I have seen is that only 1 item gets processed.  If I remove the latch works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will frequently run into problems when you mix the world of RxJava with explicit thread management, usually when it comes to testing. The RxJava toolkit is flexible enough to provide nearly everything you need.

The source for your data needs to be something like a `Subject`. In your code, you are emitting values directly to the subscriber, completely bypassing your observer chain, which is probably not what you wanted.

```
PublishSubject<String> stringStreamInput = PublishSubject.create();
```

Then, change `getPerroDetails()` to return an `Observable` that will eventually supply a result:

```
Observable<String> getPerroDetails(final String perro);
```

Then you can use the `flatMap()` operator to get the details:

```
Observable<String> stringStream = stringStreamInput
  .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .flatMap( input -> getPerroDetails(input) )
  .publish();

stringStream.connect();
```

How is `getPerroDetails()` implemented? You use one of the RxJava operators to invoke an asynchronous method:

```
Observable<String> getPerroDetails(String perro)
{
  return Observable
           .just( perro + " reloaded" )
           .delay(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
}
```